# How to test in Laravel view component @section rendered content?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, testing, laravel-9, view-components

In my Laravel 9.x project I have this code in a component's blade template:

```
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // ...
    </script>
@endsection

@section('content')
    @foreach($popups as $popup)
        <div id="{{ $popup->modal_id }}" class="popup">
            ...
        </div>
    @endforeach
@endsection
```

In my test:

```php
public function testComponentsYieldedSectionContents
{
    $component = new PopupComponent()

    // ...what's coming here?
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I tried to create a fake blade template, like this:

```
$template = <<<'BLADE'
    <div id="content">
    @yield('content')
    </div>

    <div id="scripts">
    @yield('scripts')
    </div>

    <x-popup />
    BLADE;

$result = Blade::render($template, ['id' => $popup->id]);
```

In this case the result is this:

```
<div id="content">
</div>

<div id="scripts">
</div>
```

So the component's `@section` is not arrived into the `@yield`.

How can I test what is the result in `@section('content')` and `@section('scripts')`?

Comment: Typically in Laravel you'd use a feature test, not a unit test. Pull the page via URL and check the contents there.

Comment: So if I have more than 100 of components like this, I need to create 100 layout for testing and if there is any configuration for what section should yield, then I need to create a layout for each iterations? Not sounds a Laravel way, not sounds good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel ships with an extensive testing framework. You might want to check out the method `assertSeeText($string)` which verifies whether a certain string is contained in the HTTP response.

See the documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests#assert-see-text). There is also [a list of all available assertions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests#response-assertions) if the one mentioned does not suit your exact purpose.

Comment: Actually this isn't a HTTP test, but it is a view component test. And because of this component yield content for other blade templates, in here the text what we see is an empty string.